# kafka producer reading events from wikipedia in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm quite new to Kafka and as one of my first projects I'm trying to create a kafka producer in Java which will read events from Wikipedia/Wikimedia and post them to relevant topics.

I'm looking at https://wikitech.wikimedia.org/wiki/Event_Platform/EventStreams and https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/ui/#/ for references on the wikipedia API.

I followed the basic guides for creating Kafka producers in Java, but they mainly rely on events created locally on my machine.

When looking at solutions which read events from a remote server, I see they are using libraries which are not kafka native (e.g. spring.io).

Is there a way to set up my producer with native Kafka libraries that come as part of the kafka installation package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring just wraps the native Kafka libraries to ease development and configuration. It is not required, and so, yes, you can essentially do the same that they do, but with less overhead.

> mainly rely on events created locally on my machine

Because that is easier to demo, and an implementation detail. If you pull from a remote server, then that data becomes "local" in-memory data structure at some point.

Comment: You could also use Kafka Connect - https://dev.to/madhead/kafka-connect-wikipedia-1f9h